# Returning a Postgres query in Node, server won't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, server

I've made a simple JS file that hosts a local server, and then uses Node to read a db and return the results. My aim is to create a page that just returns the rows and then later on, can create new ones.

The issue is that the console logs the results, but the server doesn't connect. I can make files that just host servers, but putting in the query stops the server from running. How can I keep my query running on a server?

Here's the code:

```
    const pg = require("pg");
    const pool = new pg.Pool({
    user: "James",
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    database: "makersBnb",
    password: "",
    port: "5432"});

    pool.query('SELECT * FROM listings', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
    pool.end();
    });
```

The table has 2 rows.
Here's the console:

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 2,
  oid: null,
  rows:
   [ { id: 2,
   listing_name: 'testListing',
   price: '5',

   description: 'description',
   owner_name: 'me',
   email: 'private@email.com',
   phone_num: '07777777771' },
 { id: 1,
   listing_name: 'a',
   price: 'b',
   description: 'c',
   owner_name: 'd',
   email: 'e',
   phone_num: 'f' } ],


_parsers:
   [ [Function: parseInteger],
     [Function: noParse],
     [Function: noParse],
     [Function: noParse],
     [Function: noParse],
     [Function: noParse],
     [Function: noParse] ],
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false,
  _getTypeParser: [Function: bound ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope that my project can give you some idea.

in postgreSQL file:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const config = require('../config');
const postgre = config.postgre;
const pool = new Pool(postgre);
module.exports = {
    getList: (/* could add params here */ callback) => {
        let param = []; //if there is params add to here in sequence,
        // for text using let param = [email]
        let query = 'select * from listings;'
        // text is sample using params;
        let text = 'select * from users where email=$1';
        return pool.query(text, param, callback)
    },
    // here you can add more functions as you like.
}
```

In app.js

```
const db = require('/postgresql') //import the file abave
app.get('/getList',(req,res)=>{
    db.getList((err,messageFromDB)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(messageFromDB.rows);
        }
    })
}
```

This is will make every time you call /getList and database (node.js server) return the result. or you can simply console.log the result or do something else.

UPDATE: when reviewed my answer and reviewed your question, you should not call `pool.end();` if you want the server continues running.